# Token displayed while logging into Google Drive

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

[image]

I am using Google drive ios sdk in my app. I use the following code during sign in process.

```
    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authViewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeDrive
                                                                                              clientID:kClientId
                                                                                          clientSecret:kClientSecret
                                                                                      keychainItemName:self.keychainID
                                                                                              delegate:self
                                                                                      finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];
[parentController presentViewController:authViewController animated:YES completion:^(void){
    NSLog(@"Presented");
}];
```

But I get a weird screen during sign in process, with token being displayed in this screen. Does anyone know why this is happening? Can I avoid this screen in any way?

Comment: I also have this displayed during OAuth2 login... however it only remains for less than a second. Does this remain on screen for you?

Comment: yes, it stays only for less than one second. but still doesn't look good. I need to remove this.

Comment: I suspect others will know how to answer this better than I could, but my guess is that you will need to dig into the Google Drive SDK and edit some Google code to present a solid colour UIView over the top of that `UIViewController` while it is visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can avoid this.It takes few seconds to load your account window.

It is an authentication process which occurs, when you Log In , It is one type of  `Authentication Request token`, which is used to log in into you Google Drive Account.

Comment: Can you please explain me how to avoid this?

Comment: as i told u it is one type of request token, which process during authentication, it ll not effect to ur app..just u can neglect it because it takes less than a sec..